Forbidden Additionally, a 403 Forbidden in php website
My website is giving error messafge which is below.
after upgraded php 8.2 in cent os 7.9 for moodle

Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.  Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I tried all the thing but no luck
Change permission
Change Ownership.
changed configuration http.conf

What was previous version of PHP? What is version of moodle? What do you change inside http.conf?

Previous version of PHP 8.0.30 and moodle version of 4.0.1+. I have just instlled php 8.2 afte that it is showing this error
